# Replacing backslashes with forward slash within double quotes

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, replace, source-code

I have some C source code which was originally developed on Windows. Now I want to work on it in Linux. There are tons of include directives that should be changed to Linux format, e.g:

```
#include "..\includes\common.h"
```

I am looking for a command-line to go through all `.h` and `.c` files, find the include directives and replace any backslash with a forward slash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`find`** + GNU **`sed`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*.[ch]" -exec sed -i '/^#include / s|\\|/|g' {} +
```

- `"*.[ch]"` - wildcard to find files with extension `.c` or `.h`
- `-i`: GNU `sed` extension to edit the files in-place without backup. FreeBSD/macOS `sed` have a similar extension where the syntax is `-i ''` instead.
- `/^#include /` - on encountering/matching line which starts with pattern: `#include`
- `s|\\|/|g` - substitute all backslashes `\` with forward slashes `/` (`\` escaped with backslash `\` for literal representation).

Comment: You might want to change your qualification regex to `/^#\s*include\W/`, because you can have whitespace after the `#`, and the whitespace (which can include tabs) after `include` is optional (e.g., ``# include"..\includes\common.h"`` is legal).  Also, I just did a quick test, and, to my surprise, whitespace ***before*** the `#` was also allowed — I don’t know whether that’s standard.  If it is, then `/^\s*#\s*include\W/`.

Answer (score -2):

I have done by below command

input.txt

```
#include "..\includes\common.h"
```

command:

```
 sed 's/\\/\//g' input.txt
```

output

```
#include "../includes/common.h"
```

Comment: Kindly let me know why down voted for my answer

Comment: There are no matching conditions in your command...it will replace any instance it faces.